# Why does Spark application fail with "ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: jdbc" as uber-jar with sbt assembly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql, sbt-assembly

I'm trying to assemble a Spark application using sbt 1.0.4 with sbt-assembly 0.14.6.

The Spark application works fine when launched in IntelliJ IDEA or `spark-submit`, but if I run the assembled uber-jar with the command line (cmd in Windows 10):

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar my-app.jar
```

I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: jdbc. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

The Spark application looks as follows.

```
package spark.main

import java.util.Properties    
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val connectionProperties = new Properties()
        connectionProperties.put("user","postgres")
        connectionProperties.put("password","postgres")
        connectionProperties.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")

        val testTable = "test_tbl"

        val spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("Postgres Test")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.file.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getName)
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "swd")
            .getOrCreate()

        val dfPg = spark.sqlContext.read.
            jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb",testTable,connectionProperties)

        dfPg.show()
    }
}
```

The following is `build.sbt`.

```
name := "apache-spark-scala"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

mainClass in Compile := Some("spark.main.Main")

libraryDependencies ++= {
    val sparkVer = "2.1.1"
    val postgreVer = "42.0.0"
    val cassandraConVer = "2.0.2"
    val configVer = "1.3.1"
    val logbackVer = "1.7.25"
    val loggingVer = "3.7.2"
    val commonsCodecVer = "1.10"
    Seq(
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVer,
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer,
        "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % cassandraConVer,
        "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % postgreVer,
        "com.typesafe" % "config" % configVer,
        "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % commonsCodecVer,
        "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % loggingVer,
        "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % logbackVer
    )
}

dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
    "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.42.Final",
    "commons-net" % "commons-net" % "2.2",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0.1"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Does anyone has any idea, why?

**[UPDATE]**

Configuration taken from offical GitHub Repository did the trick:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    xs map {_.toLowerCase} match {
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps @ (x :: xs) if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa") =>
          MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: _ =>  MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first
    }
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is almost [Why does format("kafka") fail with "Failed to find data source: kafka." with uber-jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48011941/1305344) with the differences that the other OP used Apache Maven to create an uber-jar and here it's about sbt ([sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin's configuration to be precise).

---

The short name (aka *alias*) of a data source, e.g. `jdbc` or `kafka`, are only available if the corresponding `META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` registers a `DataSourceRegister`.

For `jdbc` alias to work Spark SQL uses [META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister) with the following entry (there are others):

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider
```

[That's what ties `jdbc` alias](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcRelationProvider.scala#L27) up with the data source.

And you've excluded it from an uber-jar by the following `assemblyMergeStrategy`.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Note `case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*)` which you simply `MergeStrategy.discard`. That's the root cause.

Just to check that the "infrastructure" is available and you could use the `jdbc` data source by its fully-qualified name (not the alias), try this:

```
spark.read.
  format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider").
  load("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb")
```

You will see other problems due to missing options like `url`, but...*we're digressing*.

A solution is to `MergeStrategy.concat` all `META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` (that would create an uber-jar with all data sources, incl. the `jdbc` data source).

```
case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually the default setting, taken from [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), did the trick. See the updated question.

Comment: Can you check if `case "services" :: _ =>  MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines` alone would work. You're only interested in `META-INF/services/*` so that line alone should be enough. Thanks a lot for the update (and accepting my answer)!