# Dataproc: Uber jar fail with "Failed to find data source: kafka"

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to read from Kafka. My issue is exactly similar to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011941/why-does-formatkafka-fail-with-failed-to-find-data-source-kafka-even-wi). My code and pom.xml is very similar too. **For me, the code runs perfectly fine in my local machine. But the same code fails when I build Uber jar and run it in Dataproc cluster**. I have tried all the suggestions discussed on the original post. But none of them helps.

I get the below error:

```
Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide"
```

Can someone please help?

Spark Version: 2.4.8
Scala Version: 2.12

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>*****</groupId>
    <artifactId>*****</artifactId>
    <version>****</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


        <!-- Scala Version-->
        <scala.version>2.12.10</scala.version>
        <scala.major.version>2.12</scala.major.version>

        <!-- Spark/Hadoop Version-->
        <spark.version>2.4.8</spark.version>


        <!-- Open Source Dependencies -->
        <google.cloud.libraries.bom.version>16.2.0</google.cloud.libraries.bom.version>
        <cloud.bigdataoss.gcs.connector.version>hadoop2-2.1.3</cloud.bigdataoss.gcs.connector.version>
        <google.spark.bigquery.version>0.19.1</google.spark.bigquery.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
        <protobuf.java.version>3.14.0</protobuf.java.version>
        <com.google.guava.version>30.1-jre</com.google.guava.version>
        <google-cloud-storage.version>1.79.0</google-cloud-storage.version>

        <!-- Plugin Versions-->
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.deploy.plugin.version>2.8.2</maven.deploy.plugin.version>
        <maven.release.plugin.version>2.5.3</maven.release.plugin.version>
        <maven.site.plugin.version>3.9.1</maven.site.plugin.version>
        <scalatest.maven.plugin.version>1.0</scalatest.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven.source.plugin.version>3.2.0</maven.source.plugin.version>

        

    <dependencyManagement>
        <!-- reference : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-opensource-java/wiki/The-Google-Cloud-Platform-Libraries-BOM -->
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${google.cloud.libraries.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.scala-logging/scala-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.scala-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-logging_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.holdenkarau/spark-testing-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7_1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-secretmanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <!--<version>2.0.4</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mrpowers/spark-fast-tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mrpowers</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-fast-tests_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


       
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>[${protobuf.java.version}]</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <version>[${com.google.guava.version}]</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>${google-cloud-storage.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
            <version>${cloud.bigdataoss.gcs.connector.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <!--      Added to enable jar creation using mvn command-->
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>

                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.scalactic:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scalatest:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.spark:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>

                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.org.mainClass</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/services</resource>
                                    <file>io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider</file>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/services</resource>
                                    <file>io.grpc.NameResolverProvider</file>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>

                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
<!--                                        <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>-->
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                                        <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>

                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>repackaged.com</shadedPattern>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>com.microsoft.**</include>
                                        <include>com.google.common.**</include>
                                        <include>com.google.protobuf.**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.source.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>


</project>
```

Comment: If you run [`jar tf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html) on the shaded JAR, which Kafka packages do you see?

Comment: Those are classes from `kafka-clients` dependency.  Search for `kafka010`. The class you want is called `org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider`

Comment: No I could not find anything for kafka010. I even tried to searching just "KafkaSourceProvider". Is not available in the list.

Comment: Then that's the problem Spark is reporting. And you're saying passing `--packages org.apache.spark.spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.8` didn't work either?

Comment: Try removing `<exclude>org.apache.spark:*</exclude>`

Comment: It didn't work. Still the required class is not found in Uber jar. Also I am facing the same "failed to find data source" for bigquery. I had to pass --packages com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.22.2 to resolve. Is there something wrong in the way i am building Uber jar? Can you please help if you could?

Comment: I typically use the [`maven-assembly-plugin`'s `jar-with-dependencies`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/2308683) builder, not the shade plugin.

Comment: I had to use shade plugin since I encountered few Class not found errors. And it worked after I relocated them using the shade plugin. Is there a way to use both maven-assembly-plugin and shade plugin in same pom? Sorry if my questions are naive. This is my first project in scala.

Comment: You're effectively still getting "class not found" with that error from Spark. Scala isn't the issue here. I don't really have any other suggestions other than continue to use `--packages` for any external Spark dependencies you need.

Comment: One alternative, though, would be to add `spark.jars.packages` to your SparkSession config options